# JUnit testing using ContainsAll-assertion

Tags: mysql, junit, assertion

I'm testing a search function in the booking system I recently coded for my first semester project. My idea to test this was: I let the original search method return an arraylist of customers found in the search, fetch the list of *all* customers, and if the list of all customers contains the arraylist of customers found in the search, I assert that this works.

Note: I am prior creating a specific entry which I know I will find (hopefully, right?).

My problem is that when I call -

```
assertTrue(allCustomers.containsAll(searchResults));
```

- I get an error:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError
at TestPackages.newBookingControllerTest.testOnEnter(newBookingControllerTest.java:98)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:86)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:74)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:211)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Can anyone elaborate on why this happens? I can edit some source code in if you need. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[AssertEquals](http://junit.sourceforge.net/javadoc/org/junit/Assert.html#assertEquals%28double,%20double%29) takes two parameter, so you may see compilation error.

You should be using

```
assertTrue(allCustomers.contains(searchResults));//meaning allCustomers indeed contains searchResults
```

OR

```
 assertEquals(allCustomers.contains(searchResults), true);//Meaning boolean returned by contains api is going to be compared with true
```

Comment: Sorry, Almas! I did in fact use assertTrue from the very beginning. I corrected this now. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Nps :) But did my answer helped you to understand why you are getting assertion error?

Comment: I tried to use assertEquals to see the output. It gave me an indication of my statement is false:   junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: 
    Expected :false
Actual   :true
Does this mean that my original statement is false?

Comment: Exactly which means your array list doesn't contains searchResults. No your original statement is perfect. Just see that if you use assertTrue then create a dataset accordingly so that your arraylist would contain searchResults.

Comment: I made a for-loop printing out all Customer IDs and the search results Customer IDs and I was able to find every ID from the search results in the Customer ID-list. Shouldn't this mean that it true? Or have I misunderstood the Contains.all-function? I mean, if list1 = {A,B,C} and list2 = {A,C}. Shouldn't list1.containsAll(list2) be true?

Comment: Yes it should return true. You used contains in your example and above you are using containsAll?

Comment: I apologise again. 2nd mistake. I was a little frustrated so I wrote it quickly. I used containsAll as well, yes – I guess this is the applicable one for lists?

Comment: it should return true. So please check the list that you get and the parameter you pass to containsAll method. I am sure it works and assertTrue should work as well if list in parameter indeed is a part of list that you get.